# Secure Http Connection With Authentication Header

Tags: encryption, authentication, http, web-service, sha256

I am trying to create an authentication header algorithm that can be used for authentication on HTTP server.

Not sure it is good but it seems OK to me. I also used similar approaches for previous WS architectures and wanted be sure about this.

I would like to hear if it is suitable or contains any security flows in it.

### Authentication Headers;

`AuthX: SHA256($TIME)`
`AuthY: XOR(CONCAT($TIME + STATIC_KEY2) <- STATIC_KEY1)`

```
$TIME -> Unix epoch time in milliseconds which very dynamic
$STATIC_KEY1 -> Shared static key on both client and server. Used for XOR algorithm
$STATIC_KEY2 -> Shared static key2 on both client and server. Used for mixing XOR value.
```

### The Server will do this to validate;

`Decrypt XOR` and retrieve `$TIME` value.

1- `XOR decrypt should be understandable where STATIC_KEY1 validated`

2- `Calculated: SHA256($TIME) == AuthX`

3- `Retrieved: STATIC_KEY2 == Server hold STATIC_KEY2`

4- `$TIME should be at most 10 minutes late. This controls expired tokens`

### Dynamic Values;

1- `$TIME` is dynamic so AuthX will be dynamic for every call.

2- Due to the `$TIME` AuthY is also dynamic even though STATIC_KEY2 preserved in there.

Overall: Both header dynamically changed for each request and due to the expire control, old headers cannot be used.

Comment: There are well established primitives for message authentication, such as HMAC, i.e. send Time and HMAC(Time, Secret). This also easily extends to HMAC(Time || Body, Secret) for tamper resistance. Why invent your own?

Comment: @Peter actually your comment is what I want to hear. Because I do not know the name of this approach (HMAC). I will also check it out. Thanks!